# How to redirect requests sent to an external resource in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am trying Express redirects on a website running from localhost. Express captures the http calls made and redirects them as required using the [express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) feature. It matches the uri pattern of the requests made from the internal host.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('about')
})
```

If I am running from localhost:4200, the above code will route requests that resemble, http://localhost:4200/about.

Now let's say there is a button which on click opens https://google.com. Is there a way in express to catch this request and route it elsewhere?

Comment: what do you mean by `from the website in the localhost` ?

Comment: @hussain.codes referring to the localhost site that is running

Comment: if your localhost website has a link to some other domain, and by clicking on it you want your express server to capture that request and redirect it to somewhere else. you can't do it without using any logic on client side.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Have edited my question as well :)  
Oh, I see :( Was hoping express had an OOTB way of doing it.

Comment: your express server is only serving to localhost, so it won't be able to capture the request to google server (in this case) .

Comment: on client side you can attach event listener to `a` tag, and based on`href` value you can redirect to somewhere else, using only client side JavaScript.

Comment: Could you please write your comment as an answer to this question, which I believe is the right answer? It is NOT possible because express server is only serving to localhost. A little more explanation would also be helpful. Thanks @hussain.codes

Comment: i was wondering , what's the use case of this. instead of redirecting to google.com why can't button opens the route that you want it to redirect in the first place.

Comment: true that! it doesn't make sense in this case. But let's say I have a project that connects to different apis depending on the environment it is hosted in. Now if I am spinning up that project locally, I would want to hit some mock api instead of the actual ones. So I would set up an express server to do the redirects. Now if one of those resources happened to be hosted in a different server and could not be routed through localhost, i would not have a uri but a direct link like the google one I mentioned. That's a case I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.status(301).redirect('https://www.google.com') // status 301 or 302 for permanent or temporary redirection
})
```

or

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (true) { // make your own condition in the express middleware
      return res.status(301).redirect(`https://www.google.com`);
    }
  return next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This would work if my request was to http://localhost:4200/about in the first place. But what if the request was directly made to https://www.google.com, which needed to be redirected? As I have come to understand, it is not possible with express.